# pyhamcrest - Compare two list

Tags: python, automated-tests, pytest, python-unittest, pyhamcrest

I've just started learning python. Currently writing a unit test to assert if the elements in the expected list is present in the actual list

```
def test_compare_list_of_items():
    actual_list_of_items = ['a','b']
    expected_list_of_items = ['a']

    assert_that(actual_list_of_items, has_item(has_items(expected_list_of_items)))
```

but i'm getting errors like

```
E    Expected: a sequence containing (a sequence containing <['a']>)
E         but: was <['a', 'b']>
```

How and what sequence matcher should i use in order to assert if item 'a' in the expected list is present in the actual list?

Comment: what is `has_items`?

Comment: `has_items` match if all given items appear in the sequence, in any order https://github.com/hamcrest/PyHamcrest

Comment: sounds like you might be using the wrong function in that library then

Comment: @aws_apprentice - Would appreciate, if you could let me know the right function from the available list.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `has_item` when you should only be using `has_items`. According to the [docs](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.8/sequence_matchers/#hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containing.has_items) this takes multiple matchers which is what you want. Your function then becomes

```
def test_compare_list_of_items():
    actual_list_of_items = ['a','b']
    expected_list_of_items = ['a']

    assert_that(actual_list_of_items, has_items(*expected_list_of_items))
```

We use iterable unpacking for the list to feed as the arguments and now when you run it, it shouldn't error out.

Comment: Thanks! I tried that earlier but it doesn't work:  ```def test_compare_list_of_items():
     actual_list_of_items = ['a','b']
     expected_list_of_items = ['a']
>    assert_that(actual_list_of_items, has_items(expected_list_of_items))
E    AssertionError:
E    Expected: (a sequence containing <['a']>)
E         but: a sequence containing <['a']> was <['a', 'b']>```

Comment: you're missing the `*`, please copy my answer directly how it is, the issue is that you aren't _unpacking_ the list, note the `*` directly in front of `expected_list_of_items`

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks a lot @aws_apprentice. I read the document again and now i got what you were trying to say above. This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about `has_items` function, but can you just use something like this?

```py
assertTrue(all(item in expected_list_of_items for item in actual_list_of_items))
```

Comment: Thanks Marcos! I do have a work around but i want to use pyhamcrest matchers and hence the question. Any help would be appreciated